# How to include factors in a regression model using package "caret" in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, r-caret, dummy-variable

I am trying to build different regression models using the R package `caret`. For the data, it includes both numerical values and factors.

**Question 1**: What is the correct way to include both numerical values and factors in a regression model in `caret`?

**Question 2**: As data preprocessing (center and scale) is usually required for a regression model, how does the preprocessing work for factors?

```
library(caret)
data("mtcars")
mydata = mtcars[, -c(8,9)]
set.seed(100)
mydata$dir = sample(x=c("N", "E", "S", "W"), size = 32, replace = T)
mydata$dir = as.factor(mydata$dir)
class(mydata$dir)    # Factor with four levels

MyControl = trainControl(
  method = "repeatedcv", 
  number = 5, 
  repeats = 2, 
  verboseIter = TRUE, 
  savePredictions = "final"
)

model_glm <- train(
  hp ~ ., 
  data = mydata, 
  method = "glm", 
  metric = "RMSE", 
  preProcess = c('center', 'scale'), 
  trControl = MyControl
)

model_pls <- train(
  hp ~ ., 
  data = mydata, 
  method = "pls", 
  metric = "RMSE", 
  preProcess = c('center', 'scale'), 
  trControl = MyControl
)

model_rf <- train(
  hp ~ ., 
  data = mydata, 
  tuneLength = 5, 
  method = "ranger", 
  metric = "RMSE", 
  preProcess = c('center', 'scale'), 
  trControl = MyControl
)

model_knn <- train(
  hp ~ ., 
  data = mydata, 
  tuneLength = 5, 
  method = "knn", 
  metric = "RMSE", 
  preProcess = c('center', 'scale'), 
  trControl = MyControl
)

model_svmr <- train(
  hp ~ ., 
  data = mydata, 
  tuneLength = 5, 
  method = "svmRadial", 
  metric = "RMSE", 
  preProcess = c('center', 'scale'), 
  trControl = MyControl
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the documenation of the function [`train`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/4.47/topics/train) the input x can be:

> a data frame containing training data where samples are in rows and
> features are in columns.

And y the target input:

> A numeric or factor vector containing the outcome for each sample.

So you could use numerical and factor variables. Using the `~.` notation, you will cover all variables in x. Preprocessing numerical variables with center and scale is indeed a good approach. In the `train` function you can use the [`preProcess`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-86/topics/preProcess) argument to scale and center. This will ignore your factor variables according to the documentation:

> a matrix or data frame. Non-numeric predictors are allowed but will be
> ignored.

On page 550 of the book [Applied Predictive Modeling](https://books.google.nl/books?id=xYRDAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA547&lpg=PA547&dq=applied+predictive+modeling,+table+a1&source=bl&ots=qQnlJOoB_a&sig=HOo3gyJULZ2Sn0eJ9z6fwpTdLVw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ImSjVNDTO9CWyAT8q4KoAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=applied%20predictive%20modeling%2C%20table%20a1&f=false) (Authors Max Kuhn, Kjell Johnson), you can find what pre-processing methods are suggested for Linear regression. It says:

- Center and scaling (CS)
- Remove near-zero predictors (NZV)
- Remove highly correlated predictors (Corr)

An option to handle factor variables in preprocessing is using [dummy variables](https://conjointly.com/kb/dummy-variables/). In caret you can use the function [`dummyVars`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-91/topics/dummyVars) to convert the factor variables to a numeric variable.

**example code:**

```r
library(caret)
library(tibble)
# Data
data("mtcars")
mydata = mtcars[, -c(8,9)]
set.seed(100)
mydata$dir = sample(x=c("N", "E", "S", "W"), size = 32, replace = T)
mydata$dir = as.factor(mydata$dir)
class(mydata$dir)    # Factor with four levels
#> [1] "factor"

# Create dummy variables
dummy_mydata <- dummyVars(hp~., data = mydata)
dummy_mydata_updated <- as_tibble(predict(dummy_mydata, newdata = mydata))
# remember to include the outcome variable too
dummy_mydata_updated <- cbind(hp = mydata$hp, dummy_mydata_updated)
head(dummy_mydata_updated)
#>    hp  mpg cyl disp drat    wt  qsec gear carb dir.E dir.N dir.S dir.W
#> 1 110 21.0   6  160 3.90 2.620 16.46    4    4     1     0     0     0
#> 2 110 21.0   6  160 3.90 2.875 17.02    4    4     0     0     1     0
#> 3  93 22.8   4  108 3.85 2.320 18.61    4    1     1     0     0     0
#> 4 110 21.4   6  258 3.08 3.215 19.44    3    1     0     0     0     1
#> 5 175 18.7   8  360 3.15 3.440 17.02    3    2     0     0     1     0
#> 6 105 18.1   6  225 2.76 3.460 20.22    3    1     0     1     0     0

MyControl = trainControl(
  method = "repeatedcv", 
  number = 5, 
  repeats = 2, 
  verboseIter = TRUE, 
  savePredictions = "final"
)

model_glm <- train(
  hp ~ ., 
  data = mydata, 
  method = "glm", 
  metric = "RMSE", 
  preProcess = c('center', 'scale'), 
  trControl = MyControl
)

plot(model_glm$pred$pred, model_glm$pred$obs,
     xlab='Predicted Values',
     ylab='Actual Values',
     main='Predicted vs. Actual Values')
abline(a=0, b=1)
```

[image]

```r
model_glm_dummy <- train(
  hp ~ ., 
  data = dummy_mydata_updated, 
  method = "glm", 
  metric = "RMSE", 
  preProcess = c('center', 'scale'), 
  trControl = MyControl
)

plot(model_glm_dummy$pred$pred, model_glm_dummy$pred$obs,
     xlab='Predicted Values',
     ylab='Actual Values',
     main='Predicted vs. Actual Values')
abline(a=0, b=1)
```

[image]

```r
# Results
model_glm$results
#>   parameter     RMSE  Rsquared      MAE   RMSESD RsquaredSD    MAESD
#> 1      none 37.13849 0.7302309 32.09739 11.50226  0.2143993 10.10452
model_glm_dummy$results
#>   parameter     RMSE  Rsquared    MAE   RMSESD RsquaredSD    MAESD
#> 1      none 35.71861 0.8095385 29.678 8.959409  0.1193792 5.616908
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As you can see there is a slightly difference in results between the two models.

---

For a really usefull source check this [`website`](https://bookdown.org/rehk/stm1001_dsm_introduction_to_machine_learning_in_r/machine-learning-in-r-using-the-caret-package.html)